# Dúvida sobre Python e Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Estou precisando consultar um dataframe pandas pelo código CNAE de uma atividade. Esse dataframe é carregado a partir de um arquivo .csv

No dataframe tenho os campos CNPJ, NOME DA EMPRESA, CNAE PRINCIPAL e CNAE SECUNDÁRIO.

Essa coluna CNAE SECUNDÁRIA é uma lista com vários códigos separadas por vírgula.

Exemplo de linha do dataframe:

CNPJ; NOME DA EMPRESA; CNAE PRINCIPAL; CNAE SECUNDARIO

11.111.111/0001-11; ACME INOVAÇÕES TENCNOLÓGICAS S/A; 6204000; 6810201,6201501, 6202300
Estou precisando consultar um CNAE nesse campo de CNAE SECUNDÁRIO que na prática é uma lista.

Como fazer isso com .loc? Tentei com .isin também e não achei jeito de fazer isso.

```
cnaes = ["620151","6202300"]
empresas_df = pd.read_csv(f"empresas.csv",sep=";",encoding="latin")
empresas_df = empresas_df.loc[empresas_df['CNAE SECUNDARIO'].isin(cnaes)]
display(empresas_df)
```

Comment: [Esta pergunta já foi feita antes](/q/589828/70). Queira seguir as orientações dadas na postagem original, restaurando-a e editando. Para evitar duplicação de orientações, o espaço de comentários foi desativado aqui, mas pode ser utilizado na outra postagem se necessário (após restauração).